# SDDM error - Cannot assign to non-existent property "actionItemsVisible"

Tags: boot, updates, login, themes, ubuntu-studio

I am experiencing issues AFTER a seemingly perfect installation via USB with connected internet.
As soon as installation completes system prompts for reboot. No issues exist.
After rebooting and logging in, I proceed to run "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" from the Konsole to fully update the system.
Once updates have been downloaded and installed, it's time to reboot to affect the changes.
This is where my issues begin.

The system reboots and immediately presents me with an on-screen keyboard, behind which is an *unfamiliar* login screen with the message:

```
"The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below, please select another theme."
"file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/Main.qml:204:17: Cannot assign to non-existent property "actionItemsVisible""
```

[Image of error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgYqo.jpg)

```
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-58-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
Memory: 15.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4000
BREEZE THEME
```

I have tried *more than twice* reinstalling with identical results.
Downloaded a fresh ISO and after validating the checksum wrote the ISO to a USB.
Again a fresh installation produced the same result. No Joy!

Booted in recovery mode and tried:

```
sudo apt-get install sddm-theme-breeze
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plasma-desktop
```

No effect.

Disabled updates for everything "plasma and breeze" related. Issue persists.

Installed xbuntu desktop "sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop" and everything tested worked fine. Except it's not the "look or feel" I seek.

Finally disabled all but security updates after the last installation..
As long as general updates are disabled the system works great. Security updates are enabled and don't cause any issue after rebooting.

I would like to resolve this issue correctly and completely so I can have a fully patched, working OS. Love Ubuntu Studio! *Been using it for years!*

Any advice would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything we should know about the "seemingly perfect installation"? Did you do anything non-default when installing?

Comment: Installation was totally 100% default.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a whirl in a VM. I've never looked at Ubuntu Studio so I'll learn something in any case.

Comment: Much appreciated. ;0)

Comment: I successfully reproduced your issue in a VM by doing exactly what you said you did. I took a snapshot before doing the updates, so I will roll back to that. The question now is which update is causing the problem, which can be figured out by a process of elimination, if no other way. Will report back, but it may take a while.

Comment: Excellent Idea to debug in a VM. Thank you for providing an answer. I'll verify it locally and mark it as the solution. Thanks for investing the time... Safe Landings!

Comment: Amazing! So putting the package "ubuntustudio-default-settings" on hold allowed me to run updates in general. A few insignificant packages are being held back, but I can use the system to do my work. I am interested to know when the fix is accomplished and I will do a clean re-installation (anal... yes) Also I have to thank you Organic Marble for taking the time to sort this out so I could move forward. When I had/have questions I always look to "ask ubuntu" .. I am seriously impressed. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is caused by the package `ubuntustudio-default-settings` version 22.04.26.1

You can do your install procedure as desired, except to hold that package in its current version.

I did your install procedure in a VM, reproduced the problem, then did a binary search through installing packages until I narrowed it down to the problem package.

I'm opening a bug report on the issue (referencing this post). It's [launchpad bug 2003388](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntustudio-default-settings/+bug/2003388)

Comment: (Just FYI, I just saw Rik's response; I wouldn't worry about it (*yet anyway*), as I'd not expect Aaron or Erich to let it lie... the issue will be found & corrected)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to report this bug and helping to make Ubuntu (Studio) better.

Answer (score -1):

Good morning everyone, I installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 this morning, had the same problem. I’m not an expert, however I went to Settings → System Settings → Appearance and changed the desktop appearance. I've rebooted several times since, the error message and keyboard problem is gone. I hope this helps. Have a good day. Captain Out.

[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n773y.png)  [Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EbZs.jpg)

Comment: The issue is now resolved 'at source': https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/2003388