# Getting a Studio workstation with my prefered DE

Tags: mate, ubuntu-studio

I've been an Ubuntu Studio user since 12.04, but honestly I'm not a huge fan of KDE which is the default desktop that ships with Ubuntu Studio.
In the past, I've installed Ubuntu Studio, then installed the MATE desktop over top of it, but I've had issues with duplication of apps, default apps not loading properly, making sure JACK runs properly, having a low-latency kernel installed and updated regularly...etc...

My question would be, should I just stick with Ubuntu Studio and drop MATE on top of it, or install Ubuntu MATE and include KXStudio repositories. I'm not very keen on manually adding all my multimedia apps and settings after a vanilla install...it's a bit of work and there's always "loose ends" that go unattended.

Comment: https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/

Comment: Why not just use the desktop (Ubuntu Desktop, or *flavor*) you want, then add the Ubuntu Studio system on top of that. The Ubuntu Studio team ensure it works with all official *flavors* of Ubuntu, and given Ubuntu-MATE is an official flavor - it'll work there.   Refer to the link in mook765's prior comment.

Comment: FYI:   If you're using an official flavor; you can look at this recent question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450991/sddm-error-cannot-assign-to-non-existent-property-actionitemsvisible/1451078#1451078) which turned out being a Ubuntu Studio bug.  You'll note a user of this site reported the bug, and very soon afterwards, the bug was fixed & issue resolved.  Ubuntu Studio are a great team, and offer great support, documenting their stuff pretty well too in my opinion (*and note: I'm not a Ubuntu Studio member, so my view is from outside, though I'm within the wider Ubuntu Community*!)